# Phonograph2: how to use nextPageToken

Tags: palantir-foundry

I am syncing a data set with about 300k rows to Phonograph2 and need to make those records available via REST (End Point: /phonograph2/api/search/tables).

My requests looks as following (retrieving records after a certain timestamp):

```
{
    "tableRids": [
        "ri.phonograph2.main.table.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
     ],
    "filter": {
       "type" : "range",
        "range": {
            "field": "reco_timestamp",
            "gte": "1634408219000"
            }
        }
             
    }
}
```

The response ends with:

```
 "nextPageToken": "xxxxxxx"
```

This leads me to the following questions:

- How do I use the "nextPageToken" to retrieve the next set of results?
- Can the consumer get a list/array of pages to consume?
- Can the number of hits which are displayed until the nextPageToken is written be configured?

Comment: just to enable me to give you a better answer are you trying to expose phonograph to be consumed by an external app? If yes I would recommend that you use objects gateway instead. You should be able to find it in your stack under: https://foundrystack.example.com/workspace/documentation/product/objects-gateway/overview`

Comment: yes, we are looking to provide information to an external system. Since we have already aligned the usage of /search/tables with this system, I would like to pursue this approach.  I have to admit that I had no exposure to object-gateway, yet.

Comment: I'm hesitating to give you the answer you want to this because phonograph2 api is not something that is supposed to be hit by external services. OSS via Objects Gateway is the LTS path for these, so I would really recommend you to consume data via that API. If your organization has a special deal that enables you to develop apps against phonograph, I would encourage you to reach out via your internal support mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

We discussed this with our Palantir project support and will use Objects Gateway - as suggested. Thanks for pointing us into this direction.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).